# NetSuite Suitescript Search Access the Value

Tags: netsuite

I cannot for the life of me get the returned value from a search in NetSuite. When I use the debugger I can see the value, but I cannot access it.

```
var columns = new nlobjSearchColumn('custentity_employeenumber', null, 'max');
var results = new nlapiSearchRecord('employee', null, filters, columns);
var result = results[0].getValue('custentity_employeenumber');
```

Every time the debugger shows the result variable as null...I don't get it. I can see the value in the debugger...

[image]

I really just need the 2014103...or am I building the search wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you put a summary on a search column, you must specify the summary when you retrieve the value as well. So, because you have:

```
new nlobjSearchColumn('custentity_employeenumber', null, 'max');
```

you must retrieve the value with:

```
results[0].getValue('custentity_employeenumber', null, 'max');
```